# How to visualize a 3D mesh from an STL file using e.g. Opend3D and Python?

Tags: python, 3d, viewer, open3d

I have a STEP file which I converted into an STL file. I need the STL format to be able to extract certain features out of the 3D mesh. Further, I want to **visualize the 3D model in an interactive manner**, i.e. the user should be able to rotate and scale the model. The **code** I found, which uses **Open3D**, **doesn't work** so far:

```
import open3d as o3d

def visualize(mesh):
    vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
    vis.create_window()
    vis.add_geometry(mesh)
    vis.run()
    vis.destroy_window()

mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_model(path_stl_file)
visualize(mesh)
```

Any idea how to do it the right way? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Argh, I used the **wrong importer**. The function to be used is:

```
read_triangle_mesh(path_stl_file)
```